# Adding quantity to paypal buy now button

Tags: paypal

I want to use the buy now pay pal button to have people buy one or more tickets. The buy now button editor for generated html code doesn't allow you to specify quantity. It only allows for a quantity of 1. Is there a way to modify the html to add quantity?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Go to Custom advanced features and select yes for add quantities.